# How to retrieve a mongoid document _id after it was persisted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, mongoid4

Sorry if it's trivial, but I can't find an answer, so maybe I don't know how to ask the question.
I have a simple case:

I do:

```
SomeMongoidObject.new.save
```

And after that I want to use the id of new object to start a new background worker process. I can't find how can I get the _id of the newly created object?
The save method returns a status.

Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
mongoid_object = SomeMongoidObject.new
mongoid_object.save
```

Now you can get the id by simply doing one of the following

```
mongoid_object.id #=> id will be returned
```

**or**

```
mongoid_object["_id"]
```

**or**

```
mongoid_object._id
```

Hope this helps!